# Emacs: how to select all text in double-quotes automatically from current focused position?

Tags: emacs

After search for a long time, I refer to here.

if current position is between 2 double-quotes, is there any command can mark all text in the 2 double-quotes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're one to work with the mouse, double-clicking selects text including the double-quotes.

[expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) allows you to select expanding lexical units of text one of the stopping points is string without quotes, and the one after that is string including quotes.

Comment: double-clicking will only select one word, rather than whole text in the double-quotes.

Comment: the 'expand-region' tool is great! far beyond my expectation, thanks!

Comment: oh, yes, double clicking one of the quotes works! thanks again!

Comment: expand-region is a true gem.  Work is beginning to hopefully include it in Emacs after the upcoming 24 release.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a macro for it and save that macro for later use.
The macro would do:

1. backward search for "
2. set the mark
3. forward search for "

Comment: yes, this definitely works. and I think this should be a very generic requirement when editing text or code, there must be some existing macros or tools to do that? For I'm new to Emacs, not familiar with any LISP syntax etc...

Comment: There is got to be a better way to do this. I am new to Emacs but really, all these key combs for just selecting a word in between double quotes? Isn't there a key combination to select all the text between qoutes?

Answer (score 1):

http://emacsrocks.com/e09.html