# Selecting a clojure form in emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am using emacs for clojure development with the swank-clojure package.

I would like to copy the form under my pointer, how do I do that?

ex if my mouse pointer is currently in the inner form, it automatically gets highlighted, however how do I select it so that I can copy it. In the following form the bold bracket shows where my pointer is - (def a (str "a" "b"**)**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the beginning of the sexp: `C-M-b`, and press `C-M-<space>`

Comment: However how do I use up-list?

Comment: That should be `backward-up-list` C-M-u.  If you do any amount of serious work with any lisps, also consider using paredit.

Answer (score 2):

[expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el), which I talked about in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317094/903943) answer is exactly what you need.

<kbd>C-M-h</kbd>(`mark-defun`) also works, but expand-region is more powerful
and composable.